# Search form being split when resizing the window

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So I have created a header and with some help, I have been able to get responsivness way better than before. However I notice 2 issues:

- The search form is broken in 2 pieces
- one of the menu item text is showing on 2 or more lines. I was looking to make sure it always stay on one line.

[image]

this is my header code :

```
import React  from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';
import SiteLogo from '../assets/images/village-logo.svg';
import './Header.css';
import LoginRegisterForm from './modal/loginRegisterForm';
import LoginRegisterModalMobile from './modal/LoginRegisterModalMobile';

import TextContents from '../assets/translations/TextContents';
import { Form, InputGroup } from 'react-bootstrap'
import SearchIcon from '../assets/images/search-icon.svg';
 
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import ArrowDropDownIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowDropDown';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Constant from '../config/Constant';

import UserDataUseCase from '../data/layer/UserDataUseCase';
import Responsive from 'react-responsive-decorator';




class Header extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            anchorEl: null, 
            showLogin: false,
            isMobile: false};
    }
    
    openLogin = () => {
        this.setState({showLogin: !this.state.showLogin});
    }

    handleClick = (event) => {
        this.setState({ anchorEl: event.currentTarget });
      };
    
    handleClose = () => {
        this.setState({ anchorEl: null })
      };

    handleLogout = () => {
        this.handleClose()
        sessionStorage.clear()
        window.open("/", "_self") //to open new page
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.media({ minWidth: 768 }, () => {
              this.setState({
                isMobile: false
              });
            });
    
        this.props.media({ maxWidth: 768 }, () => {
              this.setState({
                isMobile: true
              });
            });
      }

    render() {

        const isMobile = this.state.isMobile;

        
        var authToken = sessionStorage.getItem(Constant.AUTH_TOKEN);

        var isLoggedIn;
        let loginOrProfile;

        if((authToken === null) || (authToken === 'undefined')){
            isLoggedIn = false;
        } else {
            isLoggedIn = true;
        }

        const menuLoginRegister = (<Nav.Link 
            ref="LoginRegisterModal" eventKey={1} 
            href="#" 
            onClick={this.openLogin}
            bsPrefix="header-menu-item"
            >{TextContents.MenuLoginRegister}</Nav.Link>);

        const StyledProfileMenu = withStyles({
            paper: {
                border: '1px none',
                borderRadius: "21px",
                boxShadow: "0px 8px 18px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14)",
            },
            })((props) => (
            <Menu
                elevation={0}
                getContentAnchorEl={null}
                anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: 'bottom',
                horizontal: 'left',
                }}
                transformOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'center',
                }}
                {...props}
            />
            ));

        const StyledProfileMenuItem = withStyles((theme) => ({
            root: {
                margin: "2px 30px 1px 10px",
                fontFamily: "Source Sans Pro",
                fontSize: "16px",
                color: "#616161",
                fontStyle: "normal",
                '&:hover': {
                    backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
                    color: '#ff7255'},
        
                '&:focus': {
                    backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
                    color: '#ff7255'},
            },
            }))(MenuItem);    

        const menuProfile = (
            <NavDropdown
                title={UserDataUseCase.getCurrentUserProfile().profilePic}
                id="basic-nav-dropdown"
                bsPrefix="drop-down-menu">
                <p>Sebastien Cayet</p>
                <NavDropdown.Divider className="header-divider" />
                <NavDropdown.Item bsPrefix="nav-item" href="/profile">
                {TextContents.MenuProfile}
                </NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Item bsPrefix="nav-item" href="/messages">
                {TextContents.MenuMessages}
                </NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Item href="/settings">
                {TextContents.MenuSettings}
                </NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Item href="/logout">
                {TextContents.MenuLogout}
                </NavDropdown.Item>
            </NavDropdown>);

        if (isLoggedIn) {
            loginOrProfile = menuProfile;
        } else {
            loginOrProfile = menuLoginRegister;
        }



        return (
            <div>
            <Navbar className="header-village" width="100" expand="lg">
                <Navbar.Brand href="/">
                    <img
                        src= { SiteLogo }
                        width="214"
                        height="28"
                        className="d-inline-block align-top"
                        alt="Village"
                    />
                </Navbar.Brand>
                <InputGroup className="header-search-container">
                    <InputGroup.Prepend>
                    <InputGroup.Text
                        bsPrefix="header-search-prepend"
                        id="inputGroupPrepend"
                    >
                        <img
                        src={SearchIcon}
                        width="17"
                        height="17"
                        className="header-search-img"
                        alt="Village"
                        />
                    </InputGroup.Text>
                    </InputGroup.Prepend>
                    <Form.Control
                    type="text"
                    placeholder={TextContents.SearchPlaceHolder}
                    aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend"
                    bsPrefix="header-search-form"
                    />
                    </InputGroup>
                    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                    <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                        <Nav bsPrefix="menu-inline">
                        <Nav.Link bsPrefix="header-menu-item" href="/discover">
                            {TextContents.MenuDiscover}
                        </Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link bsPrefix="header-menu-item" href="/create">
                            {TextContents.MenuCreate}
                        </Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link bsPrefix="header-menu-item" href="/howitworks">
                            {TextContents.MenuHiW}
                        </Nav.Link>
                        {loginOrProfile}
                        </Nav>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                    </Navbar>
                    { isMobile ? <LoginRegisterModalMobile displayPopUp={this.state.showLogin}onHide={() => this.setState({ showLogin: false })}/>
                    : <LoginRegisterForm displayPopUp={this.state.showLogin} onHide={() => this.setState({ showLogin: false })}/>}
            </div>
            );
        }
}

export default Responsive(Header);
```

and the css

```
.header-village {
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 2% auto;
  }
  
  .header-search-container {
    width: 470px;
    min-width: 470px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-left: 60px;
  }
  
  .header-search-prepend {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-right: 0px none;
    background-color: #f4f7f8;
  }
  
  .header-search-img {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: auto;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    margin-top: 30%;
  }
  
  .header-search-form {
    width: 430px;
    height: 40px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-left: 0px none;
    background-color: #f4f7f8;
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    text-align: left;
    color: #cecece;
  }
  
  .header-avatar-pic {
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    border-radius: 100px;
  }
  
  .header-menu-item {
    font-family: Fredoka One;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    color: #dfdfdf;
  }
  
  .header-menu-item:hover {
    color: #ff7255;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-bottom: 0px;
  }
  
  .header-divider {
    background-color: #ff7255;
  }
  
  .drop-down-menu {
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: "0px 8px 18px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14)";
  }
  .dropdown-toggle > div {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  
  .header-drop-down-name {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    color: #333333;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  .nav-item {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    color: #616161;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
  
  .nav-item:hover {
    color: #ff7255;
  }
  
  @media (max-width: 1199px) {
    .header-search-container {
      max-width: 300px;
      min-width: auto;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
      margin-left: auto;
    }
    .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-collapse {
      flex-grow: inherit;
      margin-left: auto;
    }
  }
  
  @media (max-width: 991px) {
    .header-search-container {
      margin-right: auto;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 650px) {
    .header-search-container {
      order: 1;
      margin-top: 20px;
      max-width: 100%;
    }
  }
```

So I do not understand why my search cannot keep it together instead of being split and how I can make sure the text is always fitting on one line

thanks

Comment: actually You are using hard coded width everywhere, that's why its happening, use width 100% and then make your current width to max-width, and add flex-wrap: nowrap as well on parent,

Comment: @AtulRajput thanks. I think I get it now. In case you have an idea. I am struggling with a Carousel. when resizing the windon the space between item is decreasing and I can't find a way to force it to stay fixed using this lib. react-multi-carousel

Comment: post another question for that, with the brief of problem you are facing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in another question of yours I have fixed this, so if your desktop menu is going to increase and you still want it to be together, just chnage this, add `flex-wrap: nowrap;` in desktop CSS and adjust the width, I have given you 2 classes below, use them as it is on dektop css, not in Media Query, just replace the cureent code of these 2 classes,  and it will not break ever,

```
.header-search-container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 470px;
    min-width: auto;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-left: 60px;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
 }

.header-search-form {
    max-width: 430px;
    height: 40px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-left: 0px none;
    background-color: #f4f7f8;
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    text-align: left;
    color: #cecece;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and yes, don't forget to upvote the last answer too. if need anything else mor this will not work, feel free to ask
Happy Coding.